# Missing fields in $_POST when name is longer than 65 chars

Tags: php, forms

I have problem with $_POST data.

Some fields are missing from input form when 'name' attribute is longer than 65 chars.

This works (it exists in $_POST array):

```
<input type="text" name="config_nt_articles_article_lister_adv_display:display_test65chr"/>
```

but this don't

```
<input type="text" name="config_nt_articles_article_lister_adv_display:display_test65chrlorem"/>
```

any ideas ? Maybe something in php.ini ? 
PHP Ver : PHP/5.3.8-1~dotdeb.2

Comment: Can't reproduce this, running 5.3.8 on Win7. Did you try a bare-bones test case?

Comment: Why in the world would you ever want to have that long a name?

Comment: @JanDragsbaek: It might be automatically generated by the OP's system, but in any case it's not important. There are plenty of possible reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dotdeb? I think you have installed suhosin extension, try to disable it, or tweak the /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini parameters like this:

```
suhosin.post.max_name_length = 256
suhosin.post.max_totalname_length = 1024
```

FYI: see [this](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_name_length) article :)

ps. suhosin is very nice to use in production btw :)